# export jqgrid data into excel on checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have bind the jqGrid from MVC controller , below is my jqgrid code . I want to export selected checkbox row data to csv , i have gone through all code's but every one providing sample local data, but i am binding from server to jqGrid,so when i select the checkbox rows in jqGrid and click on "Export " button the entire row should export to csv, can anybody have the solution ?

$('#jQGrid').jqGrid({

```
        search: true,
        multiboxonly: true,
        colNames: ["PayloadCorrelationId", "Export", "Asset", "DateReported", "ErrorType", "Error", "Latitude", "Longitude", "Payloadurl"],

        colModel: [
            { name: 'CorrelationId', jsonmap: 'CorrelationId', hidden: true, width: 2 },
            { name: "", editable: true, edittype: "checkbox", width: 45, sortable: false, align: "center", formatter: "checkbox", editoptions: { value: "1:0" }, formatoptions: { disabled: false } },
            { name: 'Device', jsonmap: 'Device', width: 60 }, { name: 'DateReported', jsonmap: 'DateReported', width: 100 },
              { name: 'ErrorType', jsonmap: 'ErrorType', width: 85 },
       { name: 'Error', jsonmap: 'Error', width: 140 },
       { name: 'Latitude', jsonmap: 'Latitude', width: 80 }, { name: 'Longitude', jsonmap: 'Longitude', width: 80 },
       { name: 'Payloadurl', jsonmap: 'Payloadurl', width: 180, formatter: 'link' }],

        cellEdit: true,
        pager: jQuery('#divpager'),
        rowList: [5, 20, 50, 100],
        rowNum:5,
        sortorder: "desc",
        datatype: 'json',
        width: 900,
        height: 'auto',
        viewrecords: true,           
        mtype: 'GET',
        gridview: true,
        loadonce: true,
        url: '/DataIn/DataInSearchResult/',

        emptyrecords: "No records to display",
        onSelectRow: true,
        onSelectRow: function (id, status) {
            var rowData = jQuery(this).getRowData(id);
            configid = rowData['CorrelationId'];
            alert(configid);
            // Add this    
            var ch = jQuery(this).find('#' + id + ' input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked');
            if (ch) {
                jQuery(this).find('#' + id + ' input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
            } else {
                jQuery(this).find('#' + id + ' input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
            }
            // end Add
            rowChecked = 1;
            currentrow = id;
        },
        loadComplete: function () {
            var ts = this;
            if (ts.p.reccount === 0) {
                $(this).hide();

            } else {
                $(this).show();                    
                $("#lblTotal").html($(this).getGridParam("records") + " Results");
            }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, There must be any buttons on clicking which the csv will generate from the selected check box. If it is so then loop through the grid data to filter out checked rows. You can loop through the grid data easily on firing the button event. Based on the resultant data create the csv.